# How to center columns in HTML when only using 40% of the width

Tags: html, css

I have some coding experience, but building a website is new to me. I've been able to google most of what I needed so far, but this time I've run into something I can't seem to find an answer for.

I have an HTML page, on which I have this class:

```
<style type="text/css">
        .size1of5 {
            float: left;
            width: 20%;
        }
    </style>
```

The class is used to display the data in this datalist:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" />
            <div>
                <asp:Timer ID="TimerDelay" OnTick="TimerDelay_Tick" runat="server" Interval="10000">
                </asp:Timer>
            </div>
            <div>
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="TimerDelay" EventName="Tick" />
                    </Triggers>
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" CellSpacing="3" Width="100%">
                            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <div class="size1of5">
                                    <table>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                roundimage
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                label
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                label
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:DataList>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
```

For testing purposes, the data generates 7 columns, and every ten seconds, the page turns, either to page 1 or page 2. Page 1 has 5 columns, page 2 only 2 columns.

What I'm trying to accomplish, is to center the columns when there's less than 5 columns to show. I've tried googling for a way to do this, and have tried various smaller things, but nothing have quite worked. Is it at all possible to center the columns if there's less than 5 to show?

I appreciate any help you have to offer, as I'm not much into graphic design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand the flow of your containers and UI, but based on my understanding, yes, you can center your items in your `<ItemTemplate>`. Here is a quick suggestion.

On your `<DataList>` add a class of `container` (per this example, can be any class referenced in your CSS), and then follow the pattern you've shown for nested items within the template.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; // this will center flex items
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.size1of5 {
  width: 20%;
  max-width: 20%;
  box-sizing: border-box; // optional, use case would so a border doesn't force a pre-mature wrap
}
```

This is not reflective of all your use cases, but it should get you started. Depending on your audience, you may want to use vendor prefixes for flexbox attributes.

Comment: A good suggestion, but when I try to view the page, I get an error message, saying that ItemTemplate doesn't have a "class" property. I think I already tried something similar, but I'll see if putting the class elsewhere might do it.

Comment: Putting the class on the Datalist item did the trick, however, so thank you for helping me out.